# Air resistance function when a body is thrown upwards

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, drag

When a body is thrown up with velocity $v$ and there is air resistance $F=-kv$. Then while writing acceleration $a=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}= -\frac{mg+kv}{m}$ , the minus sign is put due to sign convention. But $\mathrm{d}v$ in itself is negative. So why do we put a negative sign also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have done, you use a negative sign with mg because that force points down and you use one for kv as that force always opposes v. So when you throw the body upward, since dt is positive those negative signs will ensure that the equation makes dv negative.

You seem to want to put the knowledge of dv being negative into the equation to begin with whereas dv is what you are trying to determine. One way to possibly do that is by defining dv = -dV where by definition dV is positive. Then the equation would be
$$-dV = -(mg+kv)/m$$ or $$dV = (mg+kv)/m$$ You'd solve for dV, which would be positive, and then use dv = -dV but that's an unnecessary roundabout way of doing it.

Comment: Thnku sir for the explanation... I had the doubt in the first part of your answer that whether the signs will ensure that dv is negative or the forces acting on the downward direction will ensure that dv is negative?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that drag always opposes the motion of the body. That is, the direction of the drag force is always opposite that of the velocity vector. In particular, if we are taking the velocity of the body to be $\boldsymbol{v}$ and the *magnitude* of the drag force to be $|\boldsymbol F|=k|\boldsymbol{v}|$, then the drag force itself must be $\boldsymbol{F}=-k\boldsymbol{v}$, the minus sign ensuring that, whatever direction $\boldsymbol{v}$ points, $\boldsymbol{F}$ points the opposite direction.

In one dimension the direction is indicated by the sign of the number, but the idea of putting this minus sign in to make sure the force always points the other way remains. In particular, all of this is independent of the sign of the velocity at any given time. So the sign of the velocity might even change (a ball thrown up which falls back down later), but the equation will not.